# Android:Broadcast demo not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I am new to android, i am trying a broadcast demo, I gave my best effort by reading the documentation but its not working. Please have a look at my code:

**BroadcastDemoActivity.java**

```
package com.broadcastdemo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class BroadcastDemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static final String PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS = "com.paad.action.PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS);
        intent.putExtra("Holiday", "8th April is a holiday");
        sendBroadcast(getIntent());
    }
}
```

**Receive.java**

```
package com.broadcastdemo;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Receive extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("Holiday");
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.broadcastdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".BroadcastDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".Receive">
            <intent-filter>               
                <action android:name="com.paad.action.PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS"/>
            </intent-filter>            
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I know that i am missing something which i am not aware of, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is in the call to sendBroadcast.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS);
    intent.putExtra("Holiday", "8th April is a holiday");
    sendBroadcast(getIntent());
```

You are not sending the intent that you construct, you're sending the intent returned from getIntent(), which will be the intent that the activity was started with.

It should be

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS);
    intent.putExtra("Holiday", "8th April is a holiday");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Oh yes you are correct, now it worked :)

So is it like there is some implicit intent that started my activity? Please explain this to me
Thanks a lot for solving my problem

Comment: Yes. Do you notice in your manifest where you have an intent filter set on your Activity? That is the filter for the main launcher intent. So when a user clicks on your application's icon in the launcher, the launcher constructs an such an intent and sends it with, e.g., startActivity (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent))

Comment: Please pin-point if i have understood something wrong.

In above code PUBLIC_HOLIDAYS is a constant String, i am passing it as action parameter to the Intent. Action is defined in the manifest.xml and when that action is performed(i.e on executing the sendBroadcast(intent) method of activity), it searches in the manifest.xml file about the receiver of that intent. Now, since the Receiver is the Receive.java, and since the class extends BroadcastReceivet, the control goes into the onReceive method and displays the toast message.

Did i get it correctly? If not, then please pin-point my mistake.